uid is missing in get user request from entra to scim2.0
I have noticed that sometimes, during user provisioning, the uid is missing from the get request GET /User/Id from entra to scimgateway (based on scim2.0). The issue is not consistent and happening sometimes.
I am confused about how Entra knows the uid and if it knows, how did it miss in the Get request url. just to verify whether the uid is coming from url, I have changed the ldap backend base url in scimgateway but I am still seeing old uid.
sample-
[with uid]
GET http://ldap3.devsre.smtpi.com/Users/uid%253Damsowtpriwibfly%2540***gmail.onmicrosoft.com%252Cou%253DPeople%252Cdc%253Dchandru%252Cdc%253Dcom

[without uid]
GET https://ldap3.devsre.smtpi.com/Users/amsowtpriwibfly%2540***gmail.onmicrosoft.com 

If entra somehow knows the uid, it should send it with each request properly.
